# Avoid focus loss on Windows Notification

Tags: winapi, windows-8, window, directx

I have a full screen DirectX drawing application which I've noticed looses focus when you get one of those Windows notifications. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Windows notifications is something like [this](http://www.mydigitallife.info/wp-content/uploads/2006/04/wga-notification3.jpg)?

Comment: @Drop: That link doesn't work.

Comment: If your app is truly a fullscreen DirectX app, explorer should be [suppressing those windows notifications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff808316.aspx). Either your app is not triggering explorer's fullscreen detection, or something other than a balloon notification is causing you to lose focus.